# How to select apache2 during phpmyadmin installation on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: apache2, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to install phpmyadmin on an Ubuntu 13.04 installation, I see the option to install apache2 but I cannot put a * in between the [] like it shows. If I just press enter then apache2 does not get installed. How do I [*]?

Here is a picture of the screen:

[image: http://s14.postimg.org/8qdrvawkx/stupidmotherfuckerwontselect.png]

Answer (score 0):

<sub>OP added answer to their question - so converted to an answer</sub>

Just press the spacebar to select the item(s) then press tab to move the highligter to the ok button, and finally press enter.

An hour of my life spent learning that.